# listening for changes in the table on Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there such a thing as listening in the Oracle database from SQL or PL / SQL level?
I would like to change the data in a table, but I only need it if I update in a different table.

**Step by step:**
**1.** Change in table A
**2.** I check if the correct status is in table B
**3.** If it is not there, I am waiting for a change in status*(this is my problem - how to wait?)*. Until the status changes (controlled by JOB), I can do nothing
**4.** The status in table B is changing, it takes the next action

It is possible by using another application, eg in Java or C#. However, I would like to ask about such possibilities without an additional programming language.
I am asking for advice.

Comment: Are you looking for _triggers_?

Comment: maybe - but how build it - i try use triggers of course. I need listen only i changed Table A - not always. This is problem

Answer (score 1):

Write the trigger on B table on update of column status and whenever the update will happen in B table you can write the code in trigger to update data in A table.